# Adding a constructor for specific case of templated class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-specialization

I'm implementing a templated class `Vect<std::size_t N>`, a vector of N `double`. The general constructor takes a `std::array<double, N> const&` array, but I would like for instance for `N=2` to have a constructor taking 2 `double`, to allow lighter instantiation.

I thought of a solution that works well (see below), but it feels a bit dirty. I've gone through many questions asked here and their answers, but I haven't quite found a solution that fits my problem nicely.

I'd also like to have an alias `Vect2D` for `Vect<2>`, either with a `typedef` or anything else that does the job (for instance, my solution below).

Here is some of the code of my class `Vect`:

```
template<std::size_t N> class Vect{
protected:
    std::array<double,N> v;
public:
    Vect(const std::array<double,N>& _v = {}): v(_v) {}
    
    /*  bunch of methods & operators  */
};
```

and here is my solution for now:

```
class Vect2D : public Vect<2>{
public:
    Vect2D(double x = 0, double y = 0): Vect({x,y}) {}
    Vect2D(const Vect<2>& other): Vect(other){}
};
```

(I had to add the last line because while `Vect2D` *is* a `Vect<2>`, `Vect<2>` *is not* a `Vect2D`, so when I use operators between two `Vect2D`, the returned object has type `Vect<2>` so if needed I convert it back to `Vect2D` with this last line, for instance if the return type of a function is `Vect2D`, and what I return is the result of an operator between two `Vect2D`. It does the job, but this is partially why I feel this solution is kinda dirty.)

I'd be grateful if anyone has a nice solution, otherwise it's not a big deal since my solution does what I want anyway.

Comment: `Vect<2> x{ {1.0,2.0} };` is not ok?

Comment: If you have working code that you're wanting to have peer reviewed for improvement, your post should be on [codereview.se] instead - that's the entire reason that site exists. This site is for problems with code that prevent it from working correctly or at all.

Comment: What is your question exactly - you want to avoid `Vect2D` entirely, avoid repeating inherited constructors, or smth else? To avoid repeating constructors, can use `using Vect::Vect;`.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 it totally is; my point was to have a lighter notation, even tho it might seem unnecessary.

Comment: @rustyx I basically wanted to know if there is a cleaner way of doing what I do (and as Ken White pointed out, this might not be the place to ask that), because I feel that proceding by inheritance is kinda dirty (maybe it isnt after all). 
Also, I already tried `using Vect::Vect;` but it doesnt work to implicitely convert `Vect<2>` to `Vect2D` for instance in the case I described at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about avoiding the full class specialization and SFINAE enabling the two-double contructor only when `N` is 2?

Something as

```
template <std::size_t M = N, std::enable_if_t<(M == 2), int> = 0>
Vect (double x = 0, double y = 0): v{x,y} {}
```

> I'd also like to have an alias `Vect2D` for `Vect<2>`, either with a `typedef` or anything else that does the job

What about using `using`?

```
using Vect2D = Vect<2>;
```

The following is a full compiling example with external constructor implementation.

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t N>
class Vect
 {
   protected:
      std::array<double, N> v;

   public:
      Vect (std::array<double, N> const & v0 = {});

      template <std::size_t M = N, std::enable_if_t<(M == 2), int> = 0>
      Vect (double x = 0, double y = 0);
 };

template <std::size_t N>
Vect<N>::Vect (std::array<double, N> const & v0) : v{v0}
 { }

template <std::size_t N>
template <std::size_t M, std::enable_if_t<(M == 2), int>>
Vect<N>::Vect (double x, double y) : v{x,y}
 { }

// explicit deduction guide
Vect (double, double) -> Vect<2u>;

int main()
 {
   Vect<2u>  v2{1.0, 2.0};    // compile
   Vect      v2bis{1.0, 2.0}; // compile as Vect<2> (thanks to the deduction guide)
   // Vect<3u>  v3{1.0, 2.0}; // compilation error (no matching constructor)
 }
```

Comment: `Vect2D` -> `Vect` in the first snippet? otherwise I dont understand

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - D'Oh! And not only: `v` instead of `Vect` for the array initialization. Thanks.

Comment: that would have been my next comment ;) I thought it was a delegating constructor on purpose

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - "I thought it was a delegating constructor on purpose" - Remember the [Hanlon Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor): "never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity" :(

Comment: I'm quite new to templates so I didn't know about this `enabled_if_t` thing, thank you for bringing that up. I'm looking into this.
About the alias thing, I've already figured that out, I just added this line to not add implicit constraints on the reader, in regards to my solution which directly defines a `Vect2D`. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @AlexCord - If you didn't know `std::enabled_if_t`, look for [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) and you'll discover an entirely new world. Also [constraints and concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) are very interesting, but only starting from C++20.

Comment: @max66 Thank you for introducing me to those new concepts, C++ never ceases to amaze me by its vastness. One last quick question tho, I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to write this solution if I want to implement the constructor outside of the class.

Comment: @AlexCord - Outside of the class... it's a little nightmare. Give me some minutes and I try to add an example.

Comment: @AlexCord - Added a full example with external contructors implementations.

Comment: @AlexCord - Added also a [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for the double-float case (see `v2bis` as use example)

Comment: @max66 Thank you so much! I tried a few things but I was not quite sure about putting two `template` back to back, thank for confirming it actually is possible. Also thank you for the CTAD, I didn't know about that either. Definitely learnt a lot today, thanks again!